All urls redirected to password_expired from devise
I am using devise security gem with the regular devise gem.
I have set the password expiration option for a few weeks and whenever the expired password page is triggered I cannot access any other page. Looks like an authenticate_user action is triggered behind the scenes.
I need to be able to render the "forgot password" page which is needed if your password expired and you don't remember your current password to update it. How can I allow the forgot password page to render if the user is technically logged in and the expired password page gets triggered?
I tried creating a custom controller action which skips the authenticate_user and calls the sign_out action, but the redirect gets triggered anyways.
If I call the sign_out directly it works well.

Please share the code of your controller at in the question.
